# How to Send Raw Push Notifications from Azure Notification Hubs to iOS devices?

Tags: azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am currently using `SendDirectNotificationAsync(message, uri)` to WinPhones. I get the uri from the phone via the channel.uri returned by PushNotificationChannelManager's `CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync()`.

How do I get the equivalURI uri after registering my iPhone using `RegisterForRemoteNotifications()`?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you take your device token and remove the "<", ">" & spaces, and then set it as the tag when you register to the hub, it will be found when you try to send a notification using it as the tag via the hub by APNS.